# Running guard and growl on windows

Tags: ruby, guard, growl-for-windows

How can I run guard on windows.

I have tried to install bundler like it says on the [git](https://github.com/guard/guard) but don't know what to do now

also how can I install growl notify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble with this as well, I ended up finding a gem called ruby_gntp.
Add

```
gem 'ruby_gntp'
```

to your Gemfile and then add

```
notification :gntp
```

to your Guardfile.  This should get growl working for you and show your Guard notifications.  Although, my next issue to figure out is how to make it run a little faster.  Please let me know if you have tips on that topic!  :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't have Ruby setup on your PC

1. Go to RubyForge and download the latest version of the Ruby one-click Installer for Windows. http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167&release_id=5246
2. Download and install RubyGems. http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3
3. From command prompt, type: `gem install bundler`

To install guard you can then either add to a gem file

```
group :development do 
  gem 'guard'
end
```

then run `bundle`

**or** you can just run globally by typing: `gem install guard`

As for Growl, I'm not sure, maybe check out: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx